# postgresql headers fail to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, backtrack-linux

I've installed postgres but when I try to install it's header files I get the following error:

```
he following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libpq-dev: Depends: libpq5 (= 8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04) but 8.4.12-0ubuntu10.04 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Thats when I run `apt-get install libpq-dev`. I've already done `apt-get install postgresql` and `libpq5` would not update. (says it's already at newest edition)

Comment: The error msg says libpq5 is dependent upon 8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04, but the version you're installing is for 8.4.12-0ubuntu10.04. Did you install the correct version of PostgresSQL

Comment: You're installing a very old PostgreSQL version, and seem to be installing it on a bit of a boutique distribution (backtrack linux) that quite likely has broken packages. Consider using something a bit more commonplace if you're not comfortable wrangling apt.